# Why is there no error for this code

Tags: c++, vector, mingw

According to Stroustrup Programming.. the below code should produce a range error. The error is in the last line `i<v.size()` instead of `i<=v.size`.

I ran the code and it outputs the contents of the vector including `v[v.size]` instead of throwing an exception. I am using CodeBlocks with `mingw`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>v;
    for (int x;cin>>x;) v.push_back(x);
    for (int i=0;i<=v.size();i++) cout << "\nv[" << i << "]==" << v[i];
}
```

Comment: “According to Stroustrup Programming.. the below code should produce a range error.” Could you please quote the original text?

Answer (score 0):

What error did you expect? There is no compilation error here, but there is a runtime error. When printing the read values it will always go one step too far. If you read 2 values it will print indexes 0, 1 and 2.

This can be fixed by changing `i<=v.size()` to `i<v.size()`.

It is very common in indexed for-loops to always follow the following pattern; then you know you'll never be wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I expected a run time error. I am working through Stroustrup's book and got to exceptions. He says the above code should produce a range error which is caught by an exception (not included here)

Comment: There is two ways to access vectors in c++. Either array[n] or array.at(n). The latter is bound-checked and will throw an exception. The former however doesn't do bound-checking. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/